# curl SSL issue with RapidSSL certificates

Tags: ssl, curl

I'm getting the famous "SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed" problem when attempting to curl a domain that has a rapidssl certificate installed.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 and I have openssl installed with a huge /etc/ssl/certs directory.  I've tried using the --cacert and --capath arguments.

Nothing seems to work with this specific domain, even though when I visit the site with my web browser it authenticates the certificate.

However, when I curl https://google.com, it has no problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you provide the domain name in question, it would be easier to have an oppinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you specify `www.phaxio.com`, and not just `phaxio.com`.  The latter does not provide with a valid certificate, and could be your problem.

`https://www.phaxio.com` is using a wildcard-certificate.  This should validate as long as you specify a prefix to .phaxio.com.  This means that `phaxio.com` is invalid, but `www.phaxio.com` is valid.

However, `phaxio.com` actually presents itself with a certificate for an entirely different domain.

The date on the computer you're running `curl` on could be set to a time outside the certificates validity period.  It's valid from `18th September 2011`.

The root-certificate list could be too old - the CA-certificate is dated `19th February 2010`. (This is probably not the case in Ubuntu 10.10, though).

Comment: You would think so, but I'm getting the same problem with the www prefix.

Comment: Updated my reply.

Comment: Had to pem the rapidssl certificate and add it to my cert bundle.  That did the trick.  Rapidssl is trusted by Geotrust, and I have other domains that have rapidssl certificates that have not had this problem, so not exactly sure why I had to do this.

Comment: Interesting, so it looks like my other rapidssl certs are issued directly by Equifax, whereas this one is issued by rapidssl which has a certificate issued by geotrust.  They must have changed the way they setup their hierarchy, and the rapidssl ca is not included by default in the certificate listing.  Bummer!

Answer (score 3):

Create a file with this info: (RapidSSL+GeoTrust Certs)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

then use:

```
curl --cacert <newfile> https://www.phaxio.com
```